# How do you remove duplicates in access in a column

Tags: ms-access, vba

Do I simply use the total row (group by) feature to sort out all of the duplicate items in a column?

for example,

if I have a column that has

Lung Cancer
Lung Cancer
Cold
Meso

then it should output

Lung Cancer
Cold
Meso

Comment: your question is somewhat vague. Do you mean delete the duplicate records for the table in a column, or do you mean that you do not what them to display in the output of a query? Do you not want the entire record they are associated with to show, or just that column? Can you provide sample data and your expected result?

Comment: I would like duplicates to not display except for one record for each value that has duplicates. Also, it has to show the entire rows just not the duplicates

Comment: for example,

if I have a column that has

Lung Cancer
Lung Cancer
Cold
Meso 

then it should output

Comment: Are you outputting just this field? or is there other data with it?  If it's just this field then adding a 'Group By' on the field will give the desired results, or you could also add DESTINCT which would do essentially the same thing.

Comment: do you actually want to remove / delete them or just display only the unique ones? For the later one you would use `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a query to sort them out. And your table is as follows:

```
Disease Table        
ID     Type  
1      Lung cancer
2      Lung cancer
3      cold  
4      mesos
```

---

You can use

> SELECT DISTINCT Disease.Type
>   FROM Disease

OR

> SELECT Disease.Type
>    FROM Disease
>    GROUP BY Disease.Type